# Unable to start SonarQube server after upgrade to SonarQube 5.4

Tags: java, sonarqube5.3

I am running a SonarQube server v5.3 natively on a Virtualbox running Ubuntu 15.10. To upgrade to v5.4 I shut down the SonarQube server and updated the packages from the ubuntu update center.

I received no errors in the terminal during the upgrade, however once I attempted to view the server using the web interface I saw an errors message saying that the server encountered an error and to contact support.

In the `sonar/logs/sonar.log`-file I found the following error output:

```
2016.03.14 11:59:49 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457526462531] stopping ...
2016.03.14 11:59:51 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[web] is stopping
2016.03.14 11:59:54 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457526462531] stopped
2016.03.14 11:59:54 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457526462531] closing ...
2016.03.14 11:59:54 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457526462531] closed
2016.03.14 11:59:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service stopped
2016.03.14 11:59:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database stopped
2016.03.14 11:59:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped
2016.03.14 11:59:58 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.TerminatorThread] Process[web] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.03.14 14:14:47 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2016.03.14 14:14:47 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process6612974977583370951properties
2016.03.14 14:14:47 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
2016.03.14 14:14:47 INFO   es[o.s.s.SearchSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2016.03.14 14:14:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457961286932] version[1.7.2], pid[9670], build[e43676b/2015-09-14T09:49:53Z]
2016.03.14 14:14:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457961286932] initializing ...
2016.03.14 14:14:47 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1457961286932] loaded [], sites []
2016.03.14 14:14:48 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1457961286932] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [22.2gb], net total_space [46.6gb], types [ext4]
2016.03.14 14:14:49 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.03.14 14:14:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457961286932] initialized
2016.03.14 14:14:50 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457961286932] starting ...
2016.03.14 14:14:50 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1457961286932] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2016.03.14 14:14:50 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1457961286932] sonarqube/cYbeCEL8Tq2BF6iPVZKV0Q
2016.03.14 14:14:53 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1457961286932] new_master [sonar-1457961286932][cYbeCEL8Tq2BF6iPVZKV0Q][tomas-VirtualBox][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1457961286932}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2016.03.14 14:14:53 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1457961286932] started
2016.03.14 14:14:53 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1457961286932] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
2016.03.14 14:14:56 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2016.03.14 14:14:56 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process6200596571685378190properties
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=160m; support was removed in 8.0
2016.03.14 14:14:57 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.03.14 14:14:57 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /opt/sonar/web
2016.03.14 14:14:57 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.03.14 14:14:57 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.03.14 14:14:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.4 / 7b02df9be3cd9448699b5857586e1c6e2b28c007
2016.03.14 14:14:59 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.03.14 14:14:59 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: /opt/sonar/data
2016.03.14 14:14:59 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.03.14 14:15:00 WARN  web[o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2016.03.14 14:15:00 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1457961286932] loaded [], sites []
2016.03.14 14:15:03 WARN  web[o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility] Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: /opt/sonar
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Checkstyle / 2.4 / abe1e23436ed7b227a3a325cbf12e204a7c90fc9
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Findbugs / 3.3 / e1a76544ee6aed765106e7e2bb64072adf63ccaf
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.1 / 21e7329a632904350bb9a2e7f1b17b9967988db8
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 3.11-build4121 / 4adfce80a60a1feb2f5f729aae9edb34a103bb13
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java Properties / 1.5 / 0
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin PMD / 2.5 / 2b4e2b9de568d5436e02cd874442e005f45bf3db
2016.03.14 14:15:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.2 / d04c3cdb21f48905dd8300d1129ec90281aa6db2
2016.03.14 14:15:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2016.03.14 14:15:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.Platform] DB needs migration, entering safe mode
2016.03.14 14:15:04 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_74-b02 [linux-amd64]
2016.03.14 14:15:04 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2016.03.14 14:15:16 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2016.03.14 14:15:16 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.03.14 14:15:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.03.14 14:15:16 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
(unknown):0 warning: already initialized constant Input
(unknown):0 warning: already initialized constant Input
(unknown):0 warning: already initialized constant Input
(unknown):0 warning: already initialized constant Input
WARNING: while creating new bindings for class org.jruby.rack.RackInput,
found an existing binding; you may want to run a clean build.
2016.03.14 14:15:16 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/jruby/java/java_module.rb:5 warning: already initialized constant OrgSonarServerExceptions
file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/jruby/java/java_module.rb:5 warning: already initialized constant OrgSonarServerExceptions
file:/opt/sonar/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/jruby/java/java_module.rb:5 warning: already initialized constant OrgSonarServerExceptions
2016.03.14 14:15:17 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://192.168.40.179:9000/

    org.sonar.server.ui.JRubyFacade.getWidgets(JRubyFacade.java:191)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:440)
    org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:304)
    org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:52)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgNode.interpret(FCallNoArgNode.java:31)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
    org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
    org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:268)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:230)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallThreeArgNode.interpret(FCallThreeArgNode.java:40)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
    org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
    org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.WrapperMethod.call(WrapperMethod.java:74)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    org.jruby.ast.ArrayNode.interpretPrimitive(ArrayNode.java:94)
    org.jruby.ast.ArrayNode.interpret(ArrayNode.java:84)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81)
    org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527)
    org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223)
    org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallSpecialArgNode.interpret(FCallSpecialArgNode.java:39)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:268)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:230)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:71)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallSpecialArgNode.interpret(FCallSpecialArgNode.java:43)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:66)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
    org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:214)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
    org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgNode.java:38)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
    org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:198)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:336)
    org.jruby.runtime.BlockBody.call(BlockBody.java:73)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:224)
    org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call.gen)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.evalBlockBody(InterpretedBlock.java:384)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yield(InterpretedBlock.java:303)
    org.jruby.runtime.InterpretedBlock.yieldSpecific(InterpretedBlock.java:229)
    org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
    org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:190)
```

I was unable to post the entire error log due to the limitation of characters in the post but I believe that this will be sufficient.

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

I am happy for any feedback or comments.

## Update:

I performed another attempt to install SonarQube 5.4 and succeeded once I installed it in a clean director. However, I was not able to use the previous database that I had configured before but instead I had to start from scratch which was not such a big issue for me since I had not configured it to a big extent but I would like to know how I would solve this problem in the future.

Plugins I were using:

- FindBugs
- Git
- Java
- Java Propeties
- SVN
- Web

I was also using the embedded evaluation database which is default.

Is it possible to copy the `SONAR_HOME/data/sonar.h2.db`-file to the new directory of the new SonarQube server to keep the configuration settings and data?

Comment: Did you install v5.4 in a fresh directory or over the existing v5.3 ?

Comment: I installed it over the existing v5.3.

Comment: so libraries probably conflict. You should install in a fresh directory.

Comment: I thought it would be possible to upgrade using the native update center in ubuntu but I guess that is not working.

Comment: You didn't configure the database settings in conf/sonar.properties so the default embedded database is being used. Upgrade process is detailed at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

It happens here that you need to upgrade the database. This is visible in the below log message.

```
2016.03.14 14:15:03 WARN  web[o.s.s.p.DatabaseServerCompatibility] Database must be upgraded. Please backup database and browse /setup
```

The fix is to follow instructions and go to page http://192.168.40.179:9000/setup.

However, the fact that you have an error is odd. Any page is supposed to redirect to a explicite message page whenever the server has just started and DB needs an upgrade.

You should provide more details about your setup (installed plugins, authentication configuration, ...) so that this specific point can be investigated/reproduced.